# Sequentially remove members "repelled" by previous members

Tags: c++, c++11

I was working on a project that need to remove extra data such that the remains are not "too close" to each other, and the algorithm should be as generalize as possible. To have more general usage, I try to write in std  format.

I'm not sure if the algorithm is the best way to accomplish the goal, or if the style of coding is optimal.

```
#ifndef _REPEL
#define _REPEL

#include <algorithm>
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
#include <utility>
#endif


#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
template<class ForwardIt, class InputIt, class BinaryPredicate>
bool check_repelled(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, InputIt target, BinaryPredicate p){
    return last != std::find_if(first, last, [p, target](decltype(*first) i)->bool{ return p(i, *target); });
}
#else
template<class ForwardIt, class InputIt, class BinaryPredicate>
bool check_repelled(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, InputIt target, BinaryPredicate p){
    for(ForwardIt i = first; i != last; ++i)
        if(p(*i, *target))
            return true;
    return false;
}
#endif

template<class InputIt, class ForwardIt, class BinaryPredicate>
ForwardIt remove_copy_repelled(InputIt first, InputIt last, ForwardIt d_first, BinaryPredicate p){
    ForwardIt d_end = d_first;
    for(; first != last; ++first){
        if(!check_repelled(d_first, d_end, first, p))
            *d_end++ = *first;
    }
    return d_end;
}

template<class ForwardIt, class BinaryPredicate>
ForwardIt remove_repelled(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, BinaryPredicate p){
    ForwardIt i, j;
    for(i = first; i != last; ++i)
        if(check_repelled(first, i, i, p))
            break;
    if(i == last)
        return last;
    for(j = i; ++j != last;)
        if(!check_repelled(first, i, j, p))
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
            *i++ = std::move(*j);
#else
            std::iter_swap(i++, j);
#endif
    return i;
}
#endif
```

Possible implementation:

```
std::vector<int>x = {1,3,2,8,5,6,7};
x.erase(remove_repelled(x.begin(), x.end(), [](int a,int b)->bool{std::abs(a-b) < 2;}),x.end());
//x == {1,3,8,5}
```

Comment: This code does not compile for C++11: http://ideone.com/Chs3Gu

Comment: Just fixed the syntex, but yet have idea to handle the type.

Comment: It is still wrong (look at the updated version at http://ideone.com/Chs3Gu). Did you actually try to compile your code in C++11 mode?

Comment: The type handling & syntex is now finish, but error may be raise if the user pass a function object with const arguments.

Comment: Your `OutputIt` is not just an OutputIterator, it requires multi-pass. It is a mutable ForwardIterator.

Comment: You might want to try sorting those elements and then removing unique ranges or something similar. It might be asymptotically faster, provided that you can find a total order.

Comment: In your `check_repelled()` function, I think your lambda function is incorrect. Shouldn't it be `return p(i, *target);`?

Comment: You are right. I will add that to the code.

Answer (score 3):

In all, there's not much to complain about, but I did find a few things that might be improved. All of my comments and testing are about C++11 mode, since that's what I have conveniently available.

### Use `const` references for the predicate

Right now, the lambda in your predicate has values `a` and `b` passed by value, which is fine for primitive types such as `int` but could be relatively costly for classes such as `std::complex<double>` due to all of the overhead of construction and destruction of temporary objects.  With that said, it's only a minor change since `std::abs` creates a temporary itself, and this is a quibble with your example use of the the template rather than the template itself.  This is what I used for testing:

```
typedef std::complex<double> mytype;
auto pred = [](const mytype &a,const mytype &b)->bool{
    return abs(a-b) < 2;
};
```

### Fix the C++11 version of the code

As has been mentioned in comments, the syntax isn't quite right for the C++ version of the lambda in the template.  It should be:

```
 [p, target](decltype(*target) i)->bool{return p(i, *target); }
```

### Consider encapsulating the `erase`

It's a bit odd to have to use `x.erase()` outside of the templated function.  Putting it inside would make usage a little simpler.

### Check for empty container in `remove_copy_repelled`

I tried to exercise the `remove_copy_repelled` code.  The first thing I tried was this:

```
std::vector<mytype>x = {1,3,2,8,5,6,7};
std::vector<mytype>x2;
x2.erase(remove_copy_repelled(
    x.cbegin(), x.cend(), x2.begin(), pred), x2.end());
```

I was rewarded with a core dump.  It doesn't seem to like an empty destination container.

```
std::vector<mytype>x2;
x2.reserve(x.size());
```

This worked, but isn't particularly general, so you could do a template specialization, but there may be a better way.  In particular, you might consider constructing the destination container, perhaps using a passed parameter that is a placeholder for `push_back` or whatever the caller wishes to use to add another object to the container.